# Failed to load http://127.1.1.1:8888/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь использовать fetch():

```
function getUser() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8888')
        .then(function(response) {
           return response.json();
         })
        .then(function(response) {
            document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = response.id;
            document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = response.email;
            document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = response.password;
            document.getElementById('nick_name').innerHTML = response.nickName;
        });
}
```

Но в итоге получаю ошибку:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8888/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Пытался ставить в хедеры  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', но не помогло.

Comment: А это _set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled._ пробовали? У вас в ошибке это написано. `fetch(url, {mode:"no-cors"}).then(...)`

Comment: Kosta B., да, пробовал. В этом случае с бэкенда мне приходит body:null. А когда дебажу бэк, то там данные отправляеются.

Comment: Какой бэкенд используете?

Comment: Использую Java(Springboot). Спасибо за беспокойство, ответ уже нашел и описал ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. В моем случае надо было сделать настройку на бэке. Я использовал Java(Springboot):

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

И после этого(даже без хедеров) заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще один способ - аннотация спринга @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600), где в origins можно указать как конкретные адресы, так и все - "*".